# Regarding Custom endpoint of wishlist in woocommerce rest api

Tags: woocommerce

What are the custom endpoints for addd product in wishlist in woocommerce.I am developing a ionic app .Although i have go through the rest api documentation of woocommerce but unable to find any enpoint where i can add product to wishlist ,remove product or get all products of wishlist.

Comment: Did you get any solution?